# Why are some websites not zoomable on iPad?

Tags: html, css, ipad, zooming

Does anybody have any idea why iPad zoom (you know, where you use two fingers to enlarge the text/screen) does not work on some sites?

For example:

- facebook.com
- c3.arc.nasa.gov/nex/ ± the site that I'm working on.

Google search does not reveal anything, which makes me think it’s not a common problem.

Thanks beforehand for any insights.

Comment: that's funny, I have no problem zooming on facebook on iOS4 so unless it's something they coded ONLY for the iPad, that shouldn't happen. Can you zoom on other iOS devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This lack of zooming is by design; the website has chosen to disallow zooming. It's done with the [viewport meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag). For instance,

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

prevents zooming.

Comment: I found the viewport meta tag on my site set to "user-scalable=no" --> How did it get there? Changing it to content="initial-scale=1, width=device-width" and it works now. Thanks a lot!