# Make/detect the iPhone/iPad post back on double tap

Tags: iphone, asp.net, ipad

In an asp.net web application - without writing a mobile specific site, is there anyway of stopping double tapping on an iPhone, from zooming?  The default behaviour should be to produce a postback (and is on my Android, and in normal web browsers) - but the iPhone appears to take this as a zoom command.

So my query is, how do I get the iPhone/iPad to recognise that I actually want to do a postback?

Thanks for any help,

Mark

Comment: See [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3990151/304683) to prevent zooming - keyphrase "prevent" as in globally on your site.

Answer (score 0):

if anyone is interested, my specific issue was, I had a popup on each cell of a grid (onmouseover...) - however, to start the postback, you have to actually click on a cell in the the grid, rather than hover over it.  However, "hovering" on an iPhone is basically "clicking" on everything else - so when people were clicking, all that was happening, was the popup was showing again, and no postback was carried out - meaning people could not progress.

Solution was to detect for iPhone/Pad/Touch, and not output the "onmouseover" if those devices were detected - then the underlying click was available, and would do as designed.

Code to check for iPhone etc:

```vb
 Dim iphone as Boolean = False
    Dim userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToLower()
    ' iPhone is there
    If userAgent.Contains("iphone") Then
        iphone = True
    ElseIf userAgent.Contains("ipad") Then
        iphone = True
    ElseIf userAgent.Contains("itouch") Then
        iphone = True
    End If
```

Hope this helps anyone else with this specific issue,